# How can I apply image registration to images and their annotations with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, transformation

I wish to propagate polygon labels from a source image to a target image. The target image is just the source image, but slightly translated. I found [this code snippet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-registration-using-opencv-python/) that allows me to register a source image to a target image. If you write it as a function, it becomes:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

def register_images(
        align: np.ndarray,
        reference: np.ndarray,
):
    """
    Registers two RGB images with each other.

    Args:
        align: Image to be aligned. 
        reference: Reference image to be used for alignment.

    Returns:
        Registered image and transformation matrix.
    """
    # Convert to grayscale if needed
    _align = align.copy()
    _reference = reference.copy()
    if _align.shape[-1] == 3:
        _align = cv2.cvtColor(_align, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    if _reference.shape[-1] == 3:
        _reference = cv2.cvtColor(_reference, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    height, width = _reference.shape

    # Create ORB detector with 5000 features
    orb_detector = cv2.ORB_create(500)

    # Find the keypoint and descriptors
    # The first arg is the image, second arg is the mask (not required in this case).
    kp1, d1 = orb_detector.detectAndCompute(_align, None)
    kp2, d2 = orb_detector.detectAndCompute(_reference, None)

    # Match features between the two images
    # We create a Brute Force matcher with Hamming distance as measurement mode.
    matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

    # Match the two sets of descriptors
    matches = list(matcher.match(d1, d2))

    # Sort matches on the basis of their Hamming distance and select the top 90 % matches forward
    matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance)
    matches = matches[:int(len(matches) * 0.9)]
    no_of_matches = len(matches)

    # Define empty matrices of shape no_of_matches * 2
    p1 = np.zeros((no_of_matches, 2))
    p2 = np.zeros((no_of_matches, 2))
    for i in range(len(matches)):
        p1[i, :] = kp1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt
        p2[i, :] = kp2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt

    # Find the homography matrix and use it to transform the colored image wrt the reference
    homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC)
    transformed_img = cv2.warpPerspective(align, homography, (width, height))

    return transformed_img, homography
```

Now, I can access the transformed image and the homography matrix used for aligning the two images. What I don't understand how to do is how can I apply the same trasformation also to polygon and bounding boxes used to annotate the image.

In patricular, annotations are in COCO format, which means you can access coordinates as follows:

```py
x0, y0, width, height = bounding_box
```

And annotations are a list of polygon coordinates:

```py
segmentations = [poly1, poly2, poly3, ...]  # segmentations are a list of polygons
for poly in segmentations:
    x_coords = poly[0::2]  # x coordinates are integer values on the even index in the poly list
    y_coords = poly[1::2]  # y coordinates are integer values on the odd index in the poly list
```

Once I access the x and y coordinates, how can I apply the homography matrix?

Comment: You have to do it point-by-point. Convert your bounding box to top-left and bottom-right coordinates. x0,y0 is top left. So bottom-right is x0+width,y0+height. Then reformat by adding a third coordinate of 1, as (x,y,1). Then project those points with the homography matrix (matrix multiply). Then convert x1,y1 back to width and height. Width = x1-x0, Height = y1-y0, to form your bounding box again, if that is desired.  If this does not work, you might have to invert the homography matrix first. I cannot recall if it is a forward or inverse transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Polygons

Given any polygon, run it through `perspectiveTransform()` along with the homography matrix. That is all.

`perspectiveTransform()` takes care of all the linear algebra, including extension of `(x,y)` points to `(x,y,1)`, the obvious matrix multiplication, dividing by that added `w` dimension and dropping the added dimension.

Make sure the polygon is given as a numpy array. If OpenCV decides to play dumb, make sure the array's shape is like `(N, 1, 2)` given N points of (x,y) coordinates. `dtype` can also make it play dumb. It might want floats, maybe of a specific width.

### Boxes

Whatever types of box you start with, you'll have to calculate the corner points of it. Now it's a *polygon*. Next: see above.

If you transform an axis-aligned bounding box like that, it will likely no longer appear axis-aligned due to the homography (perspective, shear, rotation, ...). If you need an axis-aligned box around your transformed box or polygon, call `boundingRect()` on the set of points.

It's not enough to transform just the top left and bottom right corner of a box. If the transformation is a general rotation (or anything other than translation), and you interpreted the transformed points as the corners of a new axis-aligned box, that box would be *broken*. It would not align with the part of the image that it used to describe.

[image: imagine The Foot of Cupid squashing it, Monty Python style]

<sup>[first box picture from Creativity103 on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/creative_stock/25069988352) and [thumbnail of second box picture from someone on getty](https://www.gettyimages.de/detail/foto/smashed-box-with-fragile-tape-all-around-it-lizenzfreies-bild/172697414)</sup>

---

OpenCV homographies are given in *forward* sense. They work as-is on points with `perspectiveTransform()`.

You may, or may *not*, need to invert the homography. This depends on how you calculated it. `np.linalg.inv()` would do that and there is probably some function in OpenCV as well.

The `warp...()` functions implicitly invert their given homography because the sampling algorithm needs it like that. When given the `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` flag, the passed homography is assumed to be inverted already, hence is *not* inverted implicitly, but used directly in the "pull"-sense sampling.

Comment: If the matrices need to be inversed, the order of the images should be invested. For this use case that should be enough (No need ref->query and qurey->ref)

Comment: sure but I didn't want to get into that. it's an eventuality, something I had to clarify a *little* since it came up in a comment. OP gave no indication that there's any problem with any of that.